# Recover data from Xolo Q1000 (Touch Screen not working)

Tags: android, touchscreen, data-retrieval

I have **Xolo Q1000** android phone **rooted**. The touchscreen of this phone is not working and I do not wish to repair it as I'm buying a new phone. The only thing I want to do is retrieve data from this phone's **storage**.
I tried **ADB command shell** to do it but using "**adb devices**" doesn't show up my phone in it.
The phone has **password** on the screen, and to enable USB storage, I have to click the "**Turn on USB Storage**" button which is impossible since touch is not working.
How can I retrieve my data from the phone.

Comment: try connecting mouse to it over OTG. Also this is not right place to ask this question

Comment: sorry for asking question here, but OTG is not working on this phone

Comment: Do you have recovery installed? You can use something like CWM or TWRP recovery to enable ADB on device without clicking screen

Comment: haven't installed any recovery tool

Comment: then there is no way except you go to some repair store, and ask the guys to retrieve info directly from the memory chip. But it might be not cheaper than repair screen.